# How do I log a NSRect value with DLog()?

Tags: objective-c

I want to log the value of "frame" which contains a NSRect value. What is the correct way to do this instead of using %@ in the DLog()?

```
DLog(@"frame = %@", frame);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Dlog(@"frame = %@", NSStringFromRect(frame));
```